# TypeError: play is not a function

Tags: javascript, рекурсия

Код:

```js
async function play(connection, songs, guild_queue) {
    guild_queue.play = true;
    const music = await ytdld(songs[0], { filter: 'opus audioonly', format: 'mp3' });
    const play = connection.playOpusStream(music, { voulme: 0.5 });
    play.on('end', end => {
        console.log(end);
        songs.shift();
        if (songs.length > 0) {
            play(connection, songs, guild_queue);
        } else {
            connection.disconnect();
            guild_queue.play = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: у вас функция и переменная внутри называются одинаково, вас это не смущает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
async function play(connection,songs,guild_queue) {
  guild_queue.play = true;
  let music = await ytdld(songs[0],{filter: 'opus audioonly',format: "mp3"});
  let play = connection.playOpusStream(music,{voulme: 0.5});
  play.on('end', (end) =>{
    console.log(end);
    songs.shift();
    if(songs.length > 0) {
      // вы уже переписали play
      // там сейчас хранится результат connection.playOpusStream(music,{voulme: 0.5});
      // который не является функцией, поэтому и ошибка
      play(connection,songs,guild_queue);
    } else {
      connection.disconnect();
      guild_queue.play = true;
    } 
  })
}
```

Просто поменяйте название переменной внутри функции `play`, что бы не было оверрайда